# How to install JPA persistence provider in spring roo project?

Tags: gwt, jpa, spring-roo

I am looking [SpringSource Tool Suite with Google Integration](http://www.springsource.com/downloads/springsource-google-download?sid=622455) and I am getting that hint when I define persistence setup.

hint:"Command 'persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)"...

and help is saying that: * persistence setup - Install or updates a JPA persistence provider in your project

how can I install JPA persistance provider to my project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with another provider? i.e for Hibernate it would be something like:

`persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY`

I believe you can choose between ECLIPSELINK, HIBERNATE and OPENJPA.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it creating the project using Roo instead of the Eclipse ide.

You can do it typing this in the Roo console in Eclipse:

project --topLevelPackage com.company.projectName

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Roo, the keywords have changed. In Spring-Roo version 1.2 and above:

```
roo> jpa setup --provider ECLIPSELINK --database H2_IN_MEMORY
```

Earlier versions of the persistence framework configuration use a `persistence setup` command, which has changed to the newer `jpa setup` in light of support for configuring non-SQL databases.